# Script crashing when attempting to admin elevate

Tags: python, crash, runtime-error, registry, uac

I have a python script that I use to balance sound and (this is the more interesting part) change values in registries. To be able able to change those values, my script requests UAC elevation when it needs to.
Here is my problem: in one function, the call to another function (used for elevating) goes normally and nothing crashes, while in another function, which calls the elevation function the exact same way as the former function, keeps crashing my program.
I have discovered that the problem is in the elevation function itself, but only when being called from the function that causes it to crash.
Here is my code:

```
from ctypes import cast, POINTER
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume
import time
import sys, winreg, pyuac

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from balancer_ui import *

adminError = False

class Window(QDialog):
    def devicesetup(self):
        devices = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
        interface = devices.Activate(IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
        volume = cast(interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))
        return devices, interface, volume
        
    def setKeyValue(self, value):
        global adminError
        try:
            if not pyuac.isUserAdmin():
                adminError = False
                pyuac.runAsAdmin()
                sys.exit(0)
        except Exception as e:
            adminError = True
            self.ui.wlErrorPopup("Cannot run as Admin: ", e)
        try:
            keySet = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Bluetooth\Audio\AVRCP\CT", 0, winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)
            winreg.SetValueEx(keySet, 'DisableAbsoluteVolume', 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, value)
            winreg.CloseKey(keySet)
        except Exception as e:
            self.ui.wlErrorPopup("Error writing registry: ", e)
        return adminError
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
        self.ui.balance.valueChanged.connect(self.main)
        self.ui.volume.valueChanged.connect(self.main)
        self.ui.wireless.released.connect(self.wltoggle)
        
        def wlstatus():
            global adminError
            adminError = False
            try:
                keyRead = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Bluetooth\Audio\AVRCP\CT", 0, winreg.KEY_QUERY_VALUE)
                keyReadValue = winreg.QueryValueEx(keyRead, 'DisableAbsoluteVolume')
                errorRead = False
                winreg.CloseKey(keyRead)
            except Exception as e:
                errorRead = True
                keyReadValue = False
                if not pyuac.isUserAdmin():
                    self.ui.wlErrorPopup("There has been an error reading the registry. Wireless audio balancing will not work. The program will automatically try to fix the error. If it fails, edit the registry manually. The error is: ", e)
                try:
                    adminError = self.setKeyValue(0)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    self.ui.wlErrorPopup("Something else went wrong: ", e)
                print(e)
            return errorRead, keyReadValue, adminError

        for i in range (2):
            errorRead, keyReadValue, adminError = wlstatus()
            if adminError:
                break

        if errorRead:
            self.ui.wireless.setEnabled(False)
        elif keyReadValue[0] == 1:
            self.ui.wireless.setChecked(True)
            
        devices, interface, volume = self.devicesetup()      
        mastervolume = round(volume.GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar()*100)   
        if mastervolume == 0:
            self.ui.volumeval.setText("0")
        self.ui.volume.setValue(mastervolume)
        
        self.show()
        
    def wltoggle(self):
        try:
            if self.ui.wireless.isChecked():
                value = 98
            else:
                value = 6
            self.setKeyValue(value)
            keyReadValue = self.wlstatus()
            if keyReadValue[0] != value:
                self.ui.wlErrorPopup("Something else went wrong ", e)
        except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    self.ui.wlErrorPopup("Something else went wrong: ", e)
                    
    def main(self):
        
        devices, interface, volume = self.devicesetup()

        target = self.ui.balance.value()
        mastervolume = self.ui.volume.value()/100
        volume.SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(mastervolume, None)
        self.ui.balanceval.setText(str(target-5))
        
        if target != 5:
            targetL = (mastervolume/10)*(10-target)
            targetR = (mastervolume/10)*(target)            
        else:
            targetL = mastervolume
            targetR = mastervolume
        
        volume.SetChannelVolumeLevelScalar(0, targetL, None) 
        volume.SetChannelVolumeLevelScalar(1, targetR, None)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

So let me explain:
SetKeyValue is the function that requests UAC elevation and changes the registry value. WLstatus is the function that causes no problems when calling the SetKeyValue from within itself. WLtoggle is the function which causes pyuac functions inside the SetKeyValue function to crash the whole scipt. I get zero output in the console 99% of the time. The console restarts, and thats it. I also tried using ShellExecuteEx instead of pyuac with the same results.

I once got this in my console, no idea if it is related to the issue but ill just leave it here in case it is:

Exception ignored in: <function *compointer_base.**del** at 0x0000023A081B7380>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\MJouv\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\comtypes_*init**.py", line 956, in **del**
self.Release()
File "C:\Users\MJouv\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\comtypes_*init*_.py", line 1211, in Release
return self.__com_Release()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Edit: I also sometimes get this error:

Exception ignored in: <function *compointer_base.**del** at 0x000001BBD2CB3420>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\MJouv\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\comtypes_*init**.py", line 956, in **del**
self.Release()
File "C:\Users\MJouv\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\comtypes_*init*_.py", line 1211, in Release
return self.__com_Release()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: COM method call without VTable

Comment: The only thing I see currently is that `wltoggle` calls `self.wlstatus()` but `wlstatus` is local to `__init__` and can't be called this way.

Comment: thanks for the input, I will modify the code. That is not the part that causes the crash though. I have commented out this call (so now wltoggle only calls setkeyvalue) and the crash still happens. The problem is in the lines where pyuac is being used. If I remove the pyuac lines from the setkeyvalue function, the wltoggle function calls setkeyvalue normally and nothing crashes.

Comment: so after a bit of investigation (looking at the errors I got, as comtypes is used by the audio portion), I have discovered that if I comment out everything related to audio, the problem is gone. I have no idea why. Guess Ill just try to call the audio functions only after specific registry executions?

Comment: If your script needs elevation all the time or at least very often, it should be done at the beginning before even starting the QT app, so the not elevated process has done nothing which can interfere with the elevated child process.